# Network performance with Kubernetes

Tags: networking, docker, performance, kubernetes, calico

I am running a small real time bidder application in Docker Swarm using host mode for networking. I found that other networking modes were giving much higher latency.

Soon I plan to switch from Docker Swarm to unmanaged Kubernetes on dedicated physical hardware. Can anyone explain which networking mode is best for latency sensitive applications? Is host mode again the best performer because of lack of NAT translations?

For now I think I will try Calico for networking, because I have some experience with it and will save me time to deploy the stack.